# Add inline css to theme

Tags: functions, theme-development, theme-customizer

I have wordpress theme and I want to add custom css

So I try to add to header

```
<style>
<?php if (!empty($btn_color)){  ?> 
.btn-default{ background-color:<?php echo esc_attr($btn_color);?>; } <?php } ?>
</style>
```

But it seems it isn't good way and I need to use

```
wp_add_inline_style()
```

So how to use this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style), this function accepts 2 arguments:

`<?php wp_add_inline_style( $handle, $data ); ?>`

Take a look at this example:

```
function my_inline_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'custom-style',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom_script.css'
    );
        $btn_color = esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'my-custom-color' ) ); 
        $custom_css = "
                .btn-default{
                        background-color: {$btn_color};
                }";
        wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $my_custom_css );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_inline_css' );
```

You should have an option in your theme to specify the `background-color` and then output it using `wp_add_inline_style()`.

You also have other options, such as hooking into `wp_head()`:

```
function my_inline_css($btn_color) { 
    if ( !empty($btn_color) ) {  ?> 
        .btn-default { background-color:<?php echo esc_attr($btn_color);?>; } <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_head','my_inline_css');
```

However i don't know where that `$btn_color` value is set. You might want to add this information to your question to be able to get an accurate answer.

Comment: I would note that in this case `$btn_color` should be escaped